# How to install Windows 8+ with drives mapped as directories

Tags: windows, partitioning

I do not know if it is even feasible at installation time.

My setup is as follow :

- One 32Gb SSD
- One 1Tb HDD

On the HDD, i'd like to create two partitions, one for the programs, one for the users home.

Then i'd want to map these partitions as folders on the SSD

It would allow to have Windows fully installed on the SSD, and all of the other applications/files, on the HDD (and with that i mean the default pathes, will be on the correct drives)

I do know how to map an NTFS partition to a folder, but how shoud i do for this to work at install time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried that in VirtualBox using Windows 8 x64......

Unfortunately it seems it is NOT possible

Here are the three things i tried :

1. Using the recovery console before windows's installation to manually create my partitions

Assign the drive Letter C to the main one

Create the Folders i wanted to map (Program Files, Program Files (x86) and Users)

Use mountvol to map the folders to the partitions created for them

Install Windows

=> Does not work => The directories are moved into Windows.old

2. Moving the content of the folders after installation then map using the recovery console

=> Does not work, the recovery console does not have enough rights

3. Moving the flies from the folder to partitions (same as 2) but using a linux LiveCD

Done using GParted

Booted on the windows installation media to map the directories to the partitions using the recovery console

=> Does not work => Windows won't manage to load the Login screen

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that allows to do that via command line. I'm not sure it's doable before installation - you have to have existing folder structure to be able to mount hard drives. But have a look:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/09947e10-bf99-4ac5-93d4-5946103784ac.aspx

Comment: Using the Recovery command line, it might be doable..... I'll try that as soon as possible and tell you how it went

Comment: Failed Before installation, if the folders are created before, they will only get moved in Windows.old, will try to move them after the installation

Comment: Won't work at all, please see my answer if you've got any additional idas :)